# z3py stops while performing quantifier elimination in a loop

Tags: z3, z3py

I try to apply the following quantifier elimination in Python. In the third iteration, z3 does not return and gets stuck. I use Python 2.7.17 and Ubuntu 18.04.4.

```
from  z3 import *

for i in range(0,10) :
      n,X_0_, X_1_= Ints('n X_0_ X_1_')
      R_0_0, R__0, R_1_0, R__1= Ints('R_0_0 R__0 R_1_0 R__1')
      all=[n >= 3, X_0_ + X_1_ == n,X_0_ >= 0,R_0_0 <= X_0_, R_0_0 >= 0]
      all.extend([R_0_0 <= R__0, X_1_ >= 0, R_1_0 <= X_1_, R_1_0 >= 0, R_1_0 <= R__0, R_0_0 + R_1_0 == R__0])
      all.extend([3*R__0 > 2*n, R_1_0 > R_0_0, 3*R_1_0 <= 2*n, 3*R__1 <= 2*n])
      expr = And(*all)
      expr = Exists([R_0_0, R__0, R_1_0, R__1],expr)
      print "before:",expr
      tactic = Then(Tactic('qe'),Tactic('simplify'),Tactic('solve-eqs'))     
      expr=tactic(expr).as_expr()
      print "after:",expr
      print i
```

What am I missing? Should I for instance free some memory, etc?

Update. I noticed that when I change the order of variables in Exists, sometime it doesn't get stuck! I don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently tactic `qe` is not suitable for this small expression. Instead, tactic `qe2` should be used which does lighter weight feasibility checks. Also, simplification should be done before quantifier elimination.

So this line of the code

```
tactic = Then(Tactic('qe'),Tactic('simplify'),Tactic('solve-eqs'))
```

should be replaced by the following line

```
tactic = Then(Tactic('simplify'),Tactic('qe2'),Tactic('solve-eqs'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this question any different than the one you asked before? Here: [z3py dies trying to do quantifier elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114596/z3py-dies-trying-to-do-quantifier-elimination)

The advice is precisely the same though! If this is a different question, please be clear on what you're trying to achieve differently this time.

Comment: Here I have provided a code to reprodue the error.  I have also posted it in the link you mentioned.  I was wondering maybe it is not an issue in z3, but in my implementation.